# Summarizing categorical questionnaire data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Starting with Python, I ran into a problem that must be common but couldn't find a straightforward solution for. I have some fictional questionnaire data I would like to get meaningful descriptives on. Specifically, for each question I want to know how many times a particular response ("Yes"/"Maybe"/"No") was given.

**Input:**

```
         Question1   Question2   Question3
Answer1  Maybe       Yes         Yes
Answer2  No          Maybe       Yes
Answer3  Maybe       Maybe       No
Answer4  No          Yes         Maybe
```

Now, I'd like to get a nice overview of the number of times a particular answer was given to a  question. A preferred output would be something like this:

(Preferred) **Output:**

```
           Yes     Maybe    No
Question1  0       2        2
Question2  2       2        0
Question3  2       1        1
```

My own idea was that the solution must be in the 'groupby' command. So far I have not succeeded to get any meaningful output though:

```
df.groupby(['Question1']).sum()
      Question2 Question3
Question1                    
Maybe      YesMaybe     YesNo
No         MaybeYes  YesMaybe
```

I have generated the dummy-data with:

```
# Generate data
data = np.array([['','Question1','Question2','Question3'],['Answer1',"Maybe","Yes","Yes"],['Answer2',"No","Maybe","Yes"],['Answer3',"Maybe","Maybe","No"],['Answer4',"No","Yes","Maybe"]])          


# convert to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],index=data[1:,0],columns=data[0,1:])
```

I know this must be an easy challenge, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)


            Question1   Question2   Question3
Maybe       2.0         2.0         1.0
No          2.0         0.0         1.0
Yes         0.0         2.0         2.0
```

If you want, you can transpose it `df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).T`

```
            Maybe   No    Yes
Question1   2.0     2.0   0.0
Question2   2.0     0.0   2.0
Question3   1.0     1.0   2.0
```